# R loop consumes 5GB of RAM even when rm(df) is set

Tags: r

I've a loop to make an API call and write a CSV with the data.

After writting it to Local Disk, I've set rm(df). It starts cool, but after 10 or more calls the RAM, and the PC in general starts to slow down very hard.

Windows task manager says RStudio is using 5GB of RAM (total of my PC is 8RM).

Why is this happening if I'm removing the df after it is written to local disk?

```
library(googleAuthR)
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(tidyverse)

my_dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-10-25"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 1)


my_fetch <- function(ga_id, d) {



       df <- google_analytics(ga_id,
                   date_range = c(d, d),
                   metrics = c("totalEvents"),
                   dimensions = c("ga:date", "ga:eventCategory", 
                   "ga:eventAction", "ga:eventLabel"),
                   anti_sample = TRUE)



      filename <- paste0("tvgo-web", "-", d, ".csv")
      print(filename)
      write.csv(df, filename, row.names = FALSE)
      rm(df)
      gc()

}



my_fetches_fetches <- mapply(my_fetch, myviewID, my_dates, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Each API call as a CSV is 12 MB. It has:

```
dim(df)
[1] 135410      5
```

Comment: Try adding gc() immediately after your rm(df)

Comment: You can also have a look at Hadley Wickham's page on memory usage here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html for more context

Comment: You could always try to ```return(NULL)``` at the end of the function. I am curious what the object ```my_fetches_fetches``` looks like

Comment: @Cole is an API Call to google Analytics API, using `googleAnalyticsR` by Mark Edmonson.  I needed to make a call to the API by day because of the size of the data downloaded. I've updated the question, in case you have some performance recomendation. Ty.

Comment: @G5W thank you, that is it. It works nice and only consumes 100 MB of ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @G5W posted in comments, `gc()` after `rm(df)` will free up memory.